# Run script when virtual camera is turned on

Tags: scripts, video, webcam, ffmpeg, v4l

I know that using the `v4l2loopback` it is possible to create a virtual webcam or video device, which we can feed by sending streams using tools like `ffmpeg`.

It would be very nice to run a script automatically when the virtual webcam is switched on by an application which wants to use it.

In fact the script may run `ffmpeg` automatically to feed the virtual webcam each time it is switched on, instead of having to feed it manually each time.

Is this possible? What do you think?

Comment: You should be able to use `inotifywait -e  open virtual_webcam.dev`, where `virtual_webcam.dev` should be path to the device file.  Alternatively,  you may want to use `-e access` instead of `-e open`. Since command exits on one-shot basis, so you may want to wrap this into a `while ...do...done` loop. Let me know if this helps or answers your question, and if it does I'll turn that into proper answer.

Comment: Many thanks, I will try this in the next hours (this comment of mine will be deleted once I have updates about this).

Comment: Did you get something working?